# Finding fourth corner of parallelogram

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> If three comers of a parallelogram are (1, 1), (4,2), and (1,3), what
> are all three of the possible fourth comers?

I am solving this question from linear algebra textbook. In my opinion there will be only one possible fourth point. But answer is three possible points. How is this possible?

Comment: Draw a figure ! You will see there are 3 solutions. Please note that the vertices are not supposed to have any order...

Comment: Use https://www.teachoo.com/4279/1043/Theorem-8.6---Class-9---Diagonals-of-a-parallelogram-bisect-each-other/category/Theorems/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of a combinatorics question. Given three points from a parallelogram, how many of the edges connecting the three points will be sides of the parallelogram?

You probably drew two of the sides but which two? Well, it depends on the parallelogram...

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A(1,1),B(4,2),C(1,3)$. There are thee possibilities for point D to make a parallelogram with A,B,C.

1-ADCB (D opposite AC): Let  D(h,k), then slope equations are $m_{CD}=m_{AB}$ and $m_{BC}=m_{AD}$, we get $3k-h=6, h+3k=4 \implies k=2,h=-2 \implies  D(-2,2).$

2-ABDC (D opposite BC): $m_{DC}=m_{AB}, m_{DB}=m_{AD}$, we get $h=4, 3k-h=3 \implies D(4,4)$

3- ADBC (D opposite AB): $m_{AD}=m_{BC}, m_{AC}=m_{DB}$ we get $h+3k=4, h=4 \implies D(4,0)$.